# CMake not creating an executable

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, ros

I am clueless as to why the following CMakeLists.txt file complies but does not run. The error I am getting is:

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named main_GUI1 below /home/jay/fuerte/sandbox/tum_ardrone

My CMakeLists.txt is (sorry to include it all but its the best way I think):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)


# ------------------- add dynamic reconfigure api ------------------------------------
rosbuild_find_ros_package(dynamic_reconfigure)
include(${dynamic_reconfigure_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake)
gencfg()



# ------------------- add common files ------------------------------------
set(COMMON_SOURCE_FILES         
    src/UINode/tum_ardrone_gui.cpp  
src/UINode/RosThread.cpp  
src/UINode/PingThread.cpp 
)

set(COMMON_HEADER_FILES        
    src/UINode/tum_ardrone_gui.h 
src/UINode/RosThread.h  
src/UINode/PingThread.h  
)


#------------------set required libs and headers---------------------------
include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/TooN/include 
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/libcvd/include 
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/gvars3/include 
)  

link_directories(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/libcvd/lib 
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/gvars3/lib 
)


# ---------------------------- TEST --------------------------------------------------

# set header and source files

set(GUIA_SOURCE_FILES           
${COMMON_SOURCE_FILES}
src/commands/main_GUI1.cpp      
)

set(GUIA_HEADER_FILES        
${COMMON_HEADER_FILES}   
src/pathplanning/AStarAlgorithm.h
)

# *.ui
set(GUIA_UI_FILES        
src/UINode/tum_ardrone_gui.ui 
)

# *.qrc
set(GUIA_RESOURCE_FILES        
)

# do QT stuff
ADD_DEFINITIONS( -Wall )  #this is fine
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED) #this is fine
include(${QT_USE_FILE}) #this is fine 
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(GUIA_RESOURCE_FILES_CPP ${GUIA_RESOURCE_FILES})  #this is fine 
QT4_WRAP_UI(GUIA_UI_FILES_HPP ${GUIA_UI_FILES}) #this is fine 
QT4_WRAP_CPP(GUIA_HEADER_FILES_HPP ${GUIA_HEADER_FILES}) #error goes if i remove               include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})  above
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

# build!
rosbuild_add_executable(main_GUI1 ${GUIA_SOURCE_FILES} ${GUIA_RESOURCE_FILES_CPP}            ${GUIA_UI_FILES_HPP} ${GUIA_HEADER_FILES_HPP})
target_link_libraries(main_GUI1 ${QT_LIBRARIES} cvd)



# ---------------------------- Messages & Services --------------------------------------------------
#uncomment if you have defined messages
rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
rosbuild_gensrv()
```

I have the main_GUI1.cpp in src/commands so I do not know why I am getting this error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: To me your CMakeLists.txt looks fine assuming the external cmake files do what I think they do.

Comment: Hmm. The folder that should have the executable is bin which is off of the source tree. I am not sure that is going to be  /home/jay/fuerte/sandbox/tum_ardrone given the info you have posted.